# Reducing deposition on power supply wires

Tags: electricity, everyday-life

From my house there are two wires, i.e. a live and a ground wire which are placed on the power supply lines by a hook. They are not tightly jointed because of some reasons. These two wires are also in contact with air. So, after a few days some material gets deposited on the wire. As a result of which, when wind blows, wire starts shaking and power supply starts fluctuating too much throughout the day. So my questions are:

- What is the material that gets deposited on the wire?
- How to reduce this deposition so as to reduce the power fluctuation?

Comment: Please pardon me for my poor english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the joint is not tight, there can be [arcing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_arc) which will damage the metal surfaces.

If the joint is not airtight, most metals will [corrode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copper_wire_and_cable#Corrosion_resistance), for some metals, their oxides are less conductive.

If two dissimilar metals are in contact in a wet environment there can be an electrochemical [corrosive reaction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aluminum_wire#Joining_aluminum_and_copper_wires).

You need a **tight** join between two **clean** metal surfaces. Any surface oxidation should be removed before making the joint. The joint should be **sealed** against water. If dissimilar metals are involved it may be necessary to use an appropriate antioxidant paste.

In my part of the world, connecting household wiring to a 240V AC supply should only be carried out by qualified electricians employed by the electrical supply company. There are obvious safety issues. In particular, there are a number of different [earthing arrangements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earthing_system#IEC_terminology) - the correct arrangements need to be followed.

Comment: There is direct contact between three things. a) Power supply lines b) Household power wires which are placed on the power supply lines by a hook c) Air. Many times due to wind, wire shakes and power start fluctuating. Tighting wires in not an possible option. So, any thing else I could try?

Comment: @VarunDotCuDotCc: You mean like [this?](http://news.bbc.co.uk/1/hi/business/4802248.stm)

Comment: Yes, but in my case, it is not illegal.

Comment: Any idea about this.